# Can function $\log (-\log \left| x\right| )$ be approximated by a logarithmic function at zero?

Tags: functions, logarithms, singularity

What kind of singularity does $\log (-\log \left| x\right| )$ have at zero? Can that singularity be removed by adding or subtracting a logarithmic function?

Comment: No.  $\log(\log(x))$ does not behave like $\log(x)$ as $x\to \infty$.